# Can a bumblebee hive be positioned high above the ground?

Tags: entomology

We'd like to set up a hive for bumblebees and I wonder if it can be positioned high above the ground, for example on a balcony.

As bumblebees usually nest in holes in the ground, I'm somewhat concerned if they'd find the hive comfortable and be able to navigate back to it.

Comment: Depends on the species. Some bumblebee species makes nests in bird boxes high above ground.